# Angular - How to display EmployeeName on Label when EmployeeCode is correct

Tags: angular

In Angular-14 I have this code:

component.ts:

```
  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private employeeService: EmployeeService,
    private bsModalRef: BsModalRef,
    private modalService: BsModalService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  onSearch() {
    this.accountValue = this.createForm.value.accountNumber;
   if (this.accountValue !== undefined) {
    if (this.accountValue.length === 6) {
      this.employeeService.getEmployeeRecords(this.accountValue).subscribe({
        next: (res: any) => {
          this.allEmployeeDetail = res;
          console.log(this.allEmployeeDetail);
          this.isLoading = false;
        },
        error: (error) => {
          this.isLoading = false;
        }
      })
    }
   }
  }
```

component.html:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="employeeCode">Employee Code<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
  <input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    formControlName='employeeCode'
    id="employeeCoder"
    (input)="onSearch()"
    placeholder="employeeCode">
</div>

<label for="employeeName"></label>
```

console.log(this.allEmployeeDetail) gives as JSON response:

```
{
    "EmployeeCode": "KKT001",
    "EmployeeName": "AGBOR PTOLEMY"
}
```

employeeCode is 6 characters.

What I want to achieve is that when user enters the employeeCode into the text input, as soon as it's 6 characters, the employeeName of that particular employeeCode parameter should be displayed on the label employeeName. If it is not correct, it should display invalid.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`interpolation`](https://angular.io/guide/interpolation) to show the value when its valid like shown below!

component.css

```
.invalid {
    background-color: red;
}
```

component.ts:

```
  employeeName: string = 'invalid'; // <- changed here

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private employeeService: EmployeeService,
    private bsModalRef: BsModalRef,
    private modalService: BsModalService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  onSearch() {
    this.employeeName = 'invalid'; // <- changed here
    this.accountValue = this.createForm.value.accountNumber;
   if (this.accountValue !== undefined) {
    if (this.accountValue.length === 6) {
      this.employeeService.getEmployeeRecords(this.accountValue).subscribe({
        next: (res: any) => {
          this.allEmployeeDetail = res;
          this.employeeName = (this.allEmployeeDetail && this.allEmployeeDetail.EmployeeName) || 'invalid'; // <- changed here
          console.log(this.allEmployeeDetail);
          this.isLoading = false;
        },
        error: (error) => {
          this.isLoading = false;
        }
      })
    }
   }
  }
```

component.html:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="employeeCode">Employee Code<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
  <input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    formControlName='employeeCode'
    id="employeeCoder"
    (input)="onSearch()"
    placeholder="employeeCode">
</div>

<label for="employeeName" [ngClass]="{'invalid' : employeeName === 'invalid'}" *ngIf="createForm.value.accountNumber">employeeName</label> <!-- changed here -->
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Is there a way to make it red colour when it is invalid and also hide it when there is nothing in the text input?

Comment: Is it possible to hide the label when there is nothing in the text input

Comment: Thanks. One last thing. What about making the label red colour when it is invalid

Comment: @Ayobamilaye check my answer with ngclass

Comment: It's not giving any colour. There is no clour there

Comment: @Ayobamilaye please add the invalid css provided in the css file